# NSString strip regular \ escape characters how?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsstring, escaping

I need an efficient piece of code that strips escape characters. This is regular escapes not HTML escape characters.

Example: "\"", "\\\\", "\", "\\"

I want a general algorithm to strip any kind of escape sequences.

Could use any utility like regular expression.

```
  (NSString*) unescape:(NSString*) string {

      ....
  }
```

This is the answer I wrote:

```
-(NSString*) unescape:(NSString*) string
{

    for(int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        char a = [string characterAtIndex:i];
        if([string characterAtIndex:i] == '\\' ) {
            string = [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(i,1) withString:@""];
        }

    }
    return string;
}
```

Comment: What kind of escape characters? There are a lot types of escaping systems. C-style? HTML? What?

Comment: just regular escapes like "\\"

Comment: @userXXX in this case you can just replace `"\\\""` with `"\""`, etc.

Comment: I want a general algorithm to strip any kind of escape sequences.

Comment: How about a regex like this to strip from string, `\\[bntr\\\\"]`

Comment: @user1307179, Please check my answer. Is that helpful?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use below code for HTML escape

```
(NSString*) unescape:(NSString*) string 
{
    return [string stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

for regular Escape

```
(NSString*) unescape:(NSString*) string 
{    
    return [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\"" withString:@"\""];
}
```

Comment: I want a general algorithm that strips any kind of escape sequences. Not just "\"". Another example: "\\\\\\\\"

Comment: This will not work correctly if a string contains "\\", i.e. two backslashes, which is common in escaped strings.

Answer (score 1):

The best method that you should use is:

```
- (NSString *)stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)set
```

You would call it using:

```
string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 0):

If its URL Encoded, you are probably looking for:

```
stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex, you can try with regex pattern `\\[bntr\\\\"]`. Or use any required regex pattern here.

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:
                              @"\\[bntr\\\\"]" options:0 error:nil];

[regex replaceMatchesInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length]) withTemplate:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

I apoligize for my answer...

```
NSString *_string = @"\\\\ dfsdg \\ tr\\\\t \\\\\\tw\\\\\\\\w\\ t\\ \\\\ \\ \\\\\\  rret\\    \\\\ \\\\\\\\";
NSLog(@"%@", [_string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""]);
```

---

result is:

```
 dfsdg  trt tww t     rret
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps:

```
-(NSString *)unescape:(NSString *)string 
{
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"\\"].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:@"\\" withString:@"\\"];
    }
    else if ([string rangeOfString:@"\\\\"].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\"];
    }
    else if ([string rangeOfString:@"\\\\"].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\"];
    }
}
```

Comment: No that's not all i want to do. I would have done that myself if it is that simple

Comment: that doesn't help. I need either a brute force way to scan every single characters from start to end... OR.. use regular expression.... so if you see "\\\\" you replace it with length of ("\\\\") divided by two number of \ characters.....  "User regular expression to find/replace"